# Why isn't my graphql query reading the pageContext id? The query is not reading the id variable

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to have a dynamic query for a blog page using React and Gatsby. The below code is where I have a problem. I get a few errors:
before I click to this page I get an error:

> schema.mjs:25 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Expected undefined to be a
> GraphQL schema.
> this query works in the graphiql.

I'm trying to do it this way, because if I pass the blog through location.state, it won't build for production. If I try to refresh (gatsby-config.js has the DEV_SSR: true flag). I get this instead of the page loading:

> {   codeFrame: "No codeFrame could be generated",   sourcePosition:
> null,   sourceContent: null }

One more thing, it is a component that has the link button to this page. So it goes from a page, to a component that you click on to this page. I'm not sure that makes a difference.

```
// Blogs Article Page
const Articles = ({ location, data, pageContext }) => {
  console.log("data:", data); // undefined

  // this has the correct id that I expected to be used for the graphql query
  console.log("id", pageContext.id);
  
  return (
    <>
      <Layout location={location}>
        <FullArticlepage blog={location.state} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
};

export const Head = () => <Seo title="Articles" />;
export default Articles;

export const articleQuery = graphql`
  query ($id: String) {
    mongodbHitsWebsiteBlogs(id: { eq: $id }) {
      id
      image
      publishDate
      title
      author
      content
      heading
    }
  }
`;
```

in place of location.state, I would put in data.mongodbHitsWebsiteBlogs if the query was working.

Comment: Where is `graphql` imported from?

Comment: ```import { graphql } from "graphql";``` is at the top along with the components I imported

Comment: Import it from gatsby instead

Comment: yup, that was it. vscode auto completed that, and I didn't even think about it. I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: @adsy It's better for everybody if you post that as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

@adsy provided the insight I missed. He recognized I imported graphql from "graphql", when I should have: `import {graphql} from "gatsby"`

I'm posting this as the answer so it is clear to others. Thanks @adsy!